# How to remove the black border of the selected item of wxHtmlListBox?

Tags: wxwidgets

Our class inherits `wxHtmlListBox`, and it overrides both `GetSelectedTextColour` and `GetSelectedTextBgColour` to customize the colors, because the default background color of the selected item on Windows is light gray, and the bigger background is white. They make it difficult to visually tell which item is selected.

After overriding the two methods, though everything works good, there is an ugly black frame encompassing the selected item. The black frame also appears in the official example `htlbox`.

To recreate the problem, please follow these steps

1. Run `htlbox`.
2. Uncheck [Listbox | Draw seperators] to dismiss the distraction.
3. [Listbox | Set selection background... | (Choose a color) | Select]

and the ugly black frame appears, encompassing the selected item.

How do we remove the black frame/border? Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: which platform and wx version?

Comment: @Igor both wxMSW and wxGTK. The version is 3.1.5. It is just solved by overwriting the rectangle in `OnDrawBackground` with the one that has transparent border.

Comment: try 3.2.0. It has better theming support, especially for "dark mode".

Comment: Maybe then all those color overriding could be dropped...

Comment: @Igor I'd love to try 3.2.0, but am afraid of breaking our codes, especially wxWebView-related stuff. We're using GCC on both Windows and Linux, and on Windows it's tricky to build wxWebViewEdge. For example, we still use microsoft.web.webview2.1.0.992.28.nupkg, because a few newer versions we've tried lead to compile-time error "invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct ICoreWebView2Environment5'" when building 3.1.5. To save time from trial-and-error nightmare, we stick to the version we are familiar with.

Comment: For people who encounter the same problem, overriding `OnDrawBackground` is enough, no need to override `GetSelectedTextColour` and `GetSelectedTextBgColour`.

Comment: I completely understand. BTW, will you consider submitting an issue about the build error(s) you encounter? Also, what if you try to build 3.2.0 in your spare time. I mean you are missing a lot of fixes in the library...